# logback.groovy configuration not logging anything

Tags: java, configuration, slf4j, logback

I have the following logback.groovy configuration file, and I can't seem to understand why it isn't doing what I would like it to do.  Ideally, every message at TRACE or above should get logged to a file, and anything at WARN or above will get immediately shown on stdout.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to get this to happen at all.  Any ideas?

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder
import ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender
import ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender

import static ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.TRACE
import static ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.WARN

def bySecond = timestamp("yyyyMMdd'.'HHmmss", context.birthTime)

appender("STDOUT", ConsoleAppender) {
  encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
    pattern = "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
  }
}

appender("FILE", FileAppender) {
  file = "./logs/log-${bySecond}.log"
  encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
    pattern = "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
  }
}

logger("com.foo", WARN, ["STDOUT"])
root(TRACE, ["FILE"])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line at the beginning of your logback.groovy file (just after the last import)

```
import ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener

statusListener(OnConsoleStatusListener)
```